# Not getting exact image rotation in php using imagerotate()

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, image-rotation

I am using `imagerotate()` and `imagecreatefromstring()` function to rotate the `base64` image and update back to MySQL.
This is my code

```
    $imageData = $rs[0]['image_data'];//image from DB

    $im = imagecreatefromstring($imageData);

    $degrees = $_REQUEST['selectrotate'];//Dynamic degrees.


    ob_start();
    $destImage = imagerotate($im, $degrees, 0) ;     
    imageJPEG($destImage);

    $image_thumb =mysql_real_escape_string(ob_get_contents());
    $imageDV=$image_thumb;
    ob_end_clean();
```

Here what is happening:

```
$destImage = imagerotate($im, $degrees, 0);
```

In this line when I hard code `$degrees` replacing some values, rotation is working fine. 
But for dynamic degrees, rotation is taking +180. If dynamic value is 90 then image is rotated to 270 degrees.

Please help.

Comment: Sounds like its getting set as negative. (270° = -90°)  Is your form passing in the right value under the hood?

Comment: Yes Anthony. I am getting correct values for $_REQUEST['selectrotate'];

Comment: Also, donno if you read the PHP manual, but it rotates the image, ANTI-clockwise, so if you selected 90 degrees, and it rotates 270° degrees in the opposite direction, it's just 90° degrees anti clockwise.

See the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php

As @Anthony stated, 270° = -90°, which in turn is still 90° (But in opposite direction), so it's rotating correctly.

Comment: That's interesting, but why would it have different output for request variable versus hard coded?

Comment: Did you only hard code test with 180° ?

Comment: Zander Rootman i did tested it with all values.. its coming correct.

Comment: And my image data is coming from DB which is in base 64 format